# What is memcomputing?

Tags: computer-architecture

In recent article of [PM](http://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/a16308/memcomputer-quantum-computing-alternative/) the memcomputing is presented. But I did not understand how it works, according to the text.

What is the general principle of work for this `memcomputing`? How it is done in hard-ware?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *doesn't* work. I am paraphrasing Scott Aaronson in this answer, whose [article on the subject](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2212) gives more details.

They claim to have some way of solving the subsetsum problem efficiently. The basic gist being that they encode all of the numbers in the instance as electrical signals, and then throw all the electrical signals together in to a big melting pot. They then measure the output signal and try to find whether it contains a signal corresponding to a solution.

However, this requires an exponentially precise signal (to be able to figure out whether the particular frequency/signal you want is there) so it isn't really a viable approach to solving $NP$-complete problems. The article claims that this is likely to be resolved in the future and that the general principle of memcomputing might one day become viable but I think that claim should be taken with a grain of salt. It seems that whatever trade-off you make, be it time, energy, memory or precision, you always end up hitting some barrier that requires exponential resources.

Answer (score 3):

The answer above which claims "it doesn't work" doesn't quite make sense. Doesn't work for what? Which implementation of it? I realize I'm writing this with the luxury of 7 years having passed, but it's worth updating.

Scott Aaronson assumed in his 2015 blogpost that a MemComputer is purely an analog machine (which it was in the implementation he talked about) and used a concern that's very valid for analog machines to cast doubt on MemComputing's scalability in general. But the authors of the 2015 paper he talks about are clear that the implementation they were studying as a proof of principle is not unique. They specifically say that digital versions of it are possible. Since a machine with digital input/output doesn't need exponentially increasing precision to extract an output, you can't so easily claim that the exponential was simply moved to frequency space. (You could say that simply pointing to a different implementation is a bit cheap, but MemComputing as a concept was built over multiple papers, different papers addressing different things, this one simply didn't attempt to address scalability because it was beyond the scope. This should be possible in research.)

The general claim is simply that MemComputers leverage physics to compute in a way similar to quantum computers (except in a non-quantum system that exhibits dynamical long-range order), in the sense that long range correlations (loosely analogous to entanglement) are used to solve hard problems which can be interpreted as having such long-range correlations baked into problem statements. This would simply be a machine that is more expressive than a Turing machine (the way some people expect quantum computers to be more expressive than Turing machines) and would thus not threaten the generally held conjecture that $P\neq NP$, since that is a statement about Turing machines. Though it would clearly have implications for some versions of the Church-Turing thesis, the same way quantum computers do.

So, to answer the question: the general principle behind it is the type of dynamical long range order (a kind of collective behavior in physical systems) which has been shown to arise from time non-locality (memory).  This is why MemComputing is more than just in-memory computing: it computes *with* memory as well. As for the question of "how is it done in hardware?": the hardware implementation of Digital MemComputing Machines (DMM), the most modern instantiations of a MemComputer, is based on self-organizing logic gates. These are (among other desirable aspects) invertible and strongly correlated even at large distances. This provides a type of collective behavior which we expect to be more advantageous than mere parallelization.

For more details, see the textbook [MemComputing: Fundamentals and Applications](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/oso/9780192845320.001.0001/oso-9780192845320), by Di Ventra. This is published by Oxford University Press and is thus peer-reviewed.

---

***More details if needed:***

The above should fully answer the original questions and you may stop reading if you want to, but I want to add a couple of paragraphs for those computer scientists whose intellectual alarm bells are probably and understandably ringing right now if they haven't heard of this before.

It is true that MemComputing is perhaps a bit more uncomfortable than quantum computation from a computer science perspective, because in quantum computation, the exponential complexity of NP-complete problems is *explicitly* moved somewhere: the exponentially increasing Hilbert space which doesn't have to be simulated by a physical quantum computer since that quantum computer just *is* quantum mechanical to begin with. But MemComputing is really not so different, except that, instead of moving the exponential complexity somewhere explicitly, it addresses the exponential complexity of NP-complete problems more *implicitly*, by recognizing that NP-hard problems are so difficult precisely because they are often very interconnected. So a physical computer which is similarly interconnected may have an edge. There is, in fact, a deeper reason why MemComputers are so efficient: topology. We use the language of topological field theory to analyze the MemComputing dynamics and find that what drives DMMs towards a solution are instanton states, topological objects that aid the DMM in leveraging "global" information over "local" information in the physical phase space. This also makes DMMs incredibly noise-robust (this topological robustness is, in fact, why some people hope to develop topological quantum computers, since quantum computers are incredibly noise sensitive, hence the difficulty in realizing them.)

Another issue is that if MemComputers are classical instead of quantum, then we can simulate these classical systems *efficiently* on an ordinary computer and let those simulated DMMs solve NP-complete problems for us. Since this constitutes and algorithm on a Turing machine, it would immediately follow that $P=NP$. Yay!

But alas, no. The dynamics of a DMM are governed by non-linear differential equations. These admit chaos and quasi periodic orbits in the physical phase space, which can be a big problem. Luckily, physical DMMs don't admit chaos or quasi-periodic orbits unless a massive amount of noise is dumped on the DMM, which would cause the state of the DMM to become chaotic and preventing it from ever finding a solution more effectively than a random walk. It has been [shown](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.04899) that the noise necessary to do this to a physical DMM is equivalent to a temperature which would fry the electronics used to implement the self-organizing logic gates, so that's great. But physical noise enters the dynamics linearly, numerical noise from simulating the DMM *very much does not*.

So the theorems and studies that make us expect physical DMMs would solve NP-complete problems efficiently don't necessarily hold for simulated DMMs, since those are an entirely different beast to tame. Luckily that doesn't mean simulated DMMs can't be useful. They've been demonstrated to be useful for quantum measurements and the training of some types of neural networks. The company MemComputing Inc. uses simulated DMMs to solve industrial scale NP-complete problems (like shipping, route/schedule optimization for oil rig helicopters, and DoD applications) often by blindly receiving CNF files from them and solving them in 3SAT. This is a bit difficult, since you have to create a model that balances efficiency in simulating the system (getting a reasonably good degree of the polynomial overhead of the simulation) as well as faithfully representing the physics of a MemComputer in a way that's able to solve the type of problem at hand. MemComputing Inc. is a commercial company and therefore bound by NDAs, so unfortunately we don't have insight into their work. But it clearly works in a useful way, otherwise they'd be bankrupt.

Below is a figure of an [empirical study](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.06551.pdf) on simulated DMMs that used [hard instances that were specifically designed as benchmarks for SLS solvers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0111153.pdf) and compares the results to some typical SLSs, including the state of the art SID algorithm.

[image]

You can see that in this setting, the DMM can easily solve the hard test instances at multiple 3SAT clause to variable ratios (4.3 being the hardest) and apparently retains the polynomial scalability on these instances (some people might think that these might still be exponentials with small coefficients, but the exponential fits we do for scalability either don't converge or are really bad, while polynomial fits are good fits). It's also worthy to note that the last data-point of the hardest ratio, 4.3, took 15 hours to complete with completely un-optimized, sequential code (other than the optimized hyperparameters of the physical dynamics). Extrapolating from the scalability for the state-of-the-art SID algorithm, it would have taken SID longer than the age of the universe to complete the same data-point.

It is worth stressing that none of this should be taken as some sort of experimental evidence that $P=NP$! There are still very good heuristic and historical reasons to believe $P\neq NP$ and even if that turns out to be false, empirical studies are certainly no way to prove $P=NP$, you need a mathematical proof.